# How can I get all the comments posted on a page recommendation?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My Facebook app asks for `manage_pages` permission. My need is to retrieve the complete thread of recommendation comments, including comments and replies to comments, left by users and page owner on a Facebook page (authorized by a client via *Facebook Login*).

- Using the Graph API endpoint `/{page_id}/ratings` with a page token I get all the recommendations.
- With the endpoint `/{recommendation_id}`, can I get the recommendation's author ?
- With the endpoint `/{recommendation_id}/comments`, I get all the 1st level comments (users ones and mine)
- With the endpoint `/{recommendation_id}_{comment_id}/comments`, I only get the 2nd level comments left by me. Can I get the user comments, with their message and author ?

Comment: The documentation is a bit hazy right now, as to what user information you can actually get for people that did not actively grant your app any permissions. If anything like that is still possible, then I would expect that you only get full access after your app was reviewed.

Comment: Let's ask for the App Review in that case. Thanks